# Injecting eventPrefix and eventObject to Grid Collection in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, grid, dependency-injection, di

I've created a simple grid collection which has constructor as follows:

```
/**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool $metadataPool
     * @param string $mainTable
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $eventPrefix
     * @param mixed $eventObject
     * @param mixed $resourceModel
     * @param string $model
     * @param string|null $connection
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool $metadataPool,
        $mainTable,
        $eventPrefix,
        $eventObject,
        $resourceModel,
        $model = 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document',
        $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $entityFactory,
            $logger,
            $fetchStrategy,
            $eventManager,
            $storeManager,
            $metadataPool,
            $connection,
            $resource
        );
        $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
        $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
        $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
        $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
    }
```

My problem is that `$eventPrefix` and `$eventObjects` are not being resolved by DI. The code above results with error:

```
Missing required argument $eventPrefix of Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Field\Grid\Collection
```

What strange is `$mainTable` and `$resourceModel` are all right and everything work fine when error making lines are commented out. My di.xml looks like that:

```
<type name="Vendor\ModuleName\ResourceModel\Field\Grid\Collection">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_name_fields</argument>
        <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_name_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">field_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Field</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Do I need to add something more elsewhere to make those two strings work?

I've tried clearing var/generation, all cachers are off, I'm working in developer mode.

Comment: Did you found the solution for that issue?

Comment: @FredOroskoDias Yes, but it was so long time ago that I don't remember what was the cause. I think that it might be related with mistakes made in di.xml but not sure. I'll write an answer if I find that old code

Answer (score 4):

It was caused by a mistake in `di.xml`. It should be:

```
<type name="Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Field\Grid\Collection">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_name_fields</argument>
        <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_name_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">field_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Field</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

As you can see, `\Model` was missing. Based on my experience typos or missing folders in path are quite often root of many similar problems.